# cv2.drawContours function does not draw the contours properly

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm trying use OpenCV (4.4.0) to draw the contours of digits in image. But it doesn't work for me. Below my code:

```
# Read the input image and deskew it
im = cv2.imread('1742.jpg')

# Convert to grayscale and apply Gaussian filtering to filter noisy pixels
im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
im_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(im_gray, (5, 5), 0)

# Threshold the image
ret, im_th = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Find contours in the image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_th, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(im_th, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imshow("Contours", im_th)
```

Here is the image and the output of my code. I expect it has a green contour per digit.

[1742.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdgDk.jpg)

[image: output]

Comment: Hi Duc Khai Tong. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, add to your question version of OpenCV which you're using (for example: 4.5.0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('1742.jpg')
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(im, (5, 5), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(blur, 0, 150)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for contour in contours:
    """
    draw a rectangle around those contours on main image
    """
    [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    cv2.rectangle(im, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0, 255, 0), 1)
cv2.imshow('Final Image with Contours', im)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.imwrite('final.jpg',im)
```

I used Canny edge detection prior to the findContours method.Here is the result
[image]

If you want to draw the contours on the digits then use

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('1742.jpg')
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(im, (5, 5), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(blur, 0, 150)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edged,  cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imshow('Final Image with Contours', im)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Then the result is this
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Shashiwadana for the help, but i found that when i draw contour in im_th ( in my code) or in edged (in your code), the contour color is black. i don't know why and can't change its color, you can verify it by change your code to `cv2.drawContours(edged, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imshow('Final Image with Contours', edged)`

Comment: @DucKhaiTong It's because you are trying to draw green color contours on your thresholding applied image, im_th which is a binary image. So the case is same after applying canny edge detection. Here is the link to OpenCV documentation for [thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)